# Media query не работает

Tags: media-queries, media

Не понимаю почему не видно файлы css и не работают стили на определенной ширине страницы в 767px.

Стиль в коде подлючен так:

```
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
```

Есть файл style.css с такими значениями:

```
    @import url(tablet.css);
    @import url(mobile.css);

    @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {

    Какие-то стили

      }
```

Есть файл tablet.css с такими значениями:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

    Какие-то стили

      }
```

И есть файл mobile.css с такими значениями:

```
    @media (max-width: 767px) {

    Какие-то стили

      }
```

При ширине экрана в 767px в консоле адаптива гугла(ф12) ни одни из стилей не работают, их не видно. Сухой HTML и всё. Не могу понять почему?? Должен же работать файл mobile.css со стилями, но его не видно!

Comment: загружается ли вообще файл стилей `style.css` загружаются ли файлы `tablet.css` и `mobile.css`

Comment: Да, такое впечатление, что не грузятся на 767px. Ни один файл из стилей не отображается, на любой другой ширине экрана все ок

Comment: какие ошибки в консоли браузера?